Does the iphone private browing producing different each visit?
I am using the service called maxmind to convert visitor's ip address to location. I set up the cache in database so when the same ip addresses is requested it won't call the service but it will get the location from the ip address. However because this iphone's hidden ip address started switching ip address on each requests have doubled and I am paying a lot more money because of this since the middle of march. Is any change on the implementation for this private browsing or hidden ip address feature? If anyone knows about the update please let me know.
Log my ip address on the iphone to see if my phone will get different ip address of each request. Sometimes it does get different ip addres and sometimes it stays with the same ip address.

Do you get IPv4 or IPv6 address under private browsing?

for my test I gotta IPv4

It was added last year. Here is a post about how it works.
So far it only works in Safari, from what I can gather. While it's true that browsers made for iPhone and iPad use AppleWebKit, since the DSA and DMA came out, Apple might have to not enforce that (we haven't seen a final decision yet), but regardless, it doesn't seem to be part of AppleWebKit, but rather a Safari feature.

Basically, Safari routes you to an Apple node that relays you via their network and then to your destination. So the "final" IP is a "fake IP" so-to-speak. Well, technically, the IP is real, but it is generated by the exit node (the second relay).
Keep in mind that the second relay might have a pool of IPs. So even if you think the IP is the same as before, it might just be another person with the temporary IP of someone else. Or, it might be the same person and the temporary IPs might have a lease for a few days or hours.
Keep in mind, it works transparently for the user and it applies to all Apple devices.
There is no way for you to track the "real" IP of someone. And if you do try it, you might be in trouble if Apple finds out. The whole point is customer privacy.
At the moment the only way to "track" someone is via an "advertiser id" in apps (which, of course, can be reset). Another method was that Apple allowed users to limit the way apps track them. If the way you interface with customers is via a website, then the only way to identify them is the usual one: cookies. If they use private browsing, then it means they don't want to be tracked and you have to respect their wishes.
If you do have only a website, not an app, the only alternative I can think of for you is for you to detect the device, see if it's an iPad or iPhone, then ask the user to confirm their location, instead of automatically tracking them. To not make their user experience too terrible (and reduce backlash) you can make a disclaimer that because of private browsing, hidden IP and so on, you wish to provide good services but need their location. Also, allow them to deny (to be compliant with GDPR if they don't want to give you their real location).
